# GKE Autopilot - error on creating Gatekeeper constraints - no match for kind "K8sRequiredLabels" - ensure CRDs are installed first

Tags: kubernetes, constraints, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to setup gatekeeper on GKE-Autopilot and define required constraint. (not using GCP's policy controller at the moment).

constraint template was deployed using below manifest and can be listed/described successfully.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/master/demo/basic/templates/k8srequiredlabels_template.yaml

When trying to apply constraint I get error msg " resource mapping not found for name: "k8srequiredlabels-sidercar" namespace: "" from "constraints/k8srequirelabels.yaml": no matches for kind "K8sRequiredLabels" in version "constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1" ensure CRDs are installed first.

As I mentioned required constraint template/CRD was deployed successfully, what could be the issue here?
This issue is with all the constraint templates.

expected the constraint to be deployed successfully.

Comment: it was due to some missing CRDs and resources in the gatekeeper manifest for gke autopilot. As Autopilot doesn't allow mutation of some resources like node and namespaces that are managed by Google, the allowed resources need to be specified explicitly. after deployment of CRDs and defining resources it's working fie now.